# Autoloading is not working when class is registered through ext_localconf.php

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I'm stuck with a class not available issue. 
I got the next `composer.json` file under my extension:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Vendor\\MySitepackage\\": "Classes/"
        }
    }
}
```

Now I got a `EXT:my_sitepackage/Classes/Rendering/VideoRenderer.php` class whose namespace and name class is right.

Under my `ext_localconf.php`, I do this:

```
<?php
defined('TYPO3_MODE') or die();

(function () {
    ........
    /** @var \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\Rendering\RendererRegistry 
$rendererRegistry */
    $rendererRegistry = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\Rendering\RendererRegistry::getInstance();
    $rendererRegistry->registerRendererClass(\Vendor\MySitepackage\Rendering\VideoRenderer::class);

    ........
})();
```

However, when I flush the cache, I get the next error:

```
[ InvalidArgumentException ]                                                                             
  The class "Vendor\MySitepackage\Rendering\VideoRenderer" you are trying to register is not available
```

I checked all name classes and everything seems right.

Should I make a `composer dump-autoload` inside my extension to load the info class? Even if I do that, it says `Generated autoload files containing 0 classes`.

I feel a bit confused why this error is shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if this extensions is not loaded via composer, its `composer.json` is ignored. You must place the psr-4 info of your sitepackage extension to the root composer.json. don't forget to adopt the path which will be something like `public/typo3conf/ext/my_sitepackage/Classes`

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, Georg. I thought the own extension composer.json was taken into account. I tried to move it before to the root composer.json, but the problem is I forgot to adapt the path. Now working properly! Thanks!

Comment: I got the same issue.. changing composer.json in root doesn't solve it..